# Find the volume of a rotationally symmetric 3D body

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, jacobian

> let $S$ be the set of points $(x,y,z)$ satisfying $ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 $ and $ 0\leq z \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $
>   let $D$ be the $ 3 D $ body obtained by taking the union of all segments connecting $(0,0,0)$ to the points of $S$
>   Find the volume of the body.

Here is my trial :

Let
$g(t) = (0,0,0) + t(x,y,z)$ such that t $ \in [0,1]$
by the giving $ S $ in the question we get that :
$ D =$ {$0 \leq x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$}

so we want to do triple integral on $ D$ to find the volume : 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}
\int_0^1 r^2 \sin(\phi) {\ dr} \ d{\phi }\ d{\theta}
$$

the thing is when i move to spherical coordinates i get different answer than the basic coordinates .

Spherical Answer : $ \frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{3} $

x,y,z coordinates Answer $ \frac{5\pi}{6\sqrt{2}} $

Comment: it would help if you would write in the actual integrals you are computing and the calculations. looks like an error in arithmetic likely

Comment: i have updated the integral

Comment: Are you sure that is the answer you obtain through the spherical integral?

Comment: i am not sure of the answer i tried to calculate the question in different ways but i failed to calculate in the spherical coordinates , and according to the answer down there the one in the x,y,z is right but the one in the spherical is wrong

Comment: @Mather The answer obtained through spherical co-ordinates is correct

Comment: but the one with the  xyz is incorrect ? how ? also the body they ask in the question is it really the domain i wrote $ D $

Comment: @Mather See my answer. I'm adding more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral in cartesian co-ordinates looks like this: $I=I_1-I_2$

$\displaystyle I_1=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}\ dx\ dy=2\pi/3\\I_2=\displaystyle\int_{-\frac1{\sqrt2}}^{\frac1{\sqrt2}}\int_{-\sqrt{\frac12-y^2}}^{\sqrt{\frac12-y^2}}\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ dx\ dy$

$I_1$ is just the volume of the hemsiphere. $I_2$ gives the volume of the inverted cone with spherical base that needs to be subtracted from $I_1$.

The answer obtained is the same as the one produced by the spherical integral: $\sqrt2\pi/3$.

[image: Figure]
[image: Figure]
[image: Figure]

Comment: i sliced the domain into circules as a function of z like the one up there

Comment: I'm adding more details, just wait a sec

Comment: The domain is a collection of annular discs parallel to the $z=0$ plane. The answer above has assumed it to be a collection of complete discs

Comment: but i dont understand why i cant slice the body into discs with radius $ 1-z^2 $

Comment: Do you know a good 3D surface plotter?

Comment: no but do you know any so i can see the surface itself , also is the domain $D$ i wrote is right ? for the body the question asks for ?

Comment: @Mather, see the updated answer. The region $D$ whose volume you want is the part of the unit sphere below the inverted cone.

Comment: @Mather Do get back for any clarification.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$$\int\limits_{z=0}^{1/\sqrt{2}} \pi \left( (1 - z^2) - z^2 \right)\ dz = \int\limits_{z=0}^{1/\sqrt{2}} \pi (1 - 2 z^2)\ dz = \frac{\sqrt{2} \pi }{3}$$

Annular disk of inner radius $z$ and outer radius $\sqrt{1 - z^2}$ and thickness $dz$ (in blue).

Comment: yes i got this answer on basic coordinates but on spherical i got diffrent one

Comment: Show your full spherical integral.

Comment: i updated it without the limits

Comment: You don't have the Jacobian.

Comment: the jacobian is the integrand itself $ r^2sin(\phi) $ isn't it ?

Comment: i updated the integral

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The elemental discs are not complete; they are annular.